# Automate webpage tasks without having to have a browser open?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I know about tampermonkey/greasemonkey and have used it a fair bit, but now my task is to write a program that runs in the background and automates mundane tasks (clicking buttons, typing into input fields etc.) on a specific webpage. Running a browser in the background takes too much RAM and processing power, so I'm looking for an alternative.

So far I've found [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), but after a bit of research it looks like that it requires to have a browser open at all times as well (or maybe not? the documentation isn't that good). I thought about python scripts too, but I don't have any experience with those nor have I any idea if they can handle anything that's not basic html. If they can, does anyone know of a good tutorial for python scripts? I have used that language a few years ago, so I shouldn't really have a problem with python itself.

If python scripts aren't ideal either, is there a (preferably somewhat simple) way I could achieve what I want?

Comment: I think you should try using headless browser.. follow this link for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549954/java-selenium-how-can-i-get-the-html-of-a-webpage-without-first-loading-the-pag/38550069#38550069

Comment: correct with phantomJS or so you would be able to send requests as a browser would, without a UI

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want a script that interacts with a web UI, or a script that automates web requests.  Do you *really* need to click buttons and type into input fields?  Presumably, the data from those buttons and input fields is eventually sent to a web server.  You could skip the entire UI and just make the requests directly.  You don't need a browser for that and python is fine for doing these types of things (you don't even need `selenium`, you can just use `requests`)

On the other hand, if you're trying to test out the UI of a web page, or you actually need to interact with the web UI for some other reason, then yeah, you'll need an application (like a web browser) that's capable of rendering the UI so you can interact with it.

Comment: You're right, I haven't really thought of that. What you suggested would be great, but I am not really experienced regarding anything related to web requests - meaning I understand HTML and javascript, but I never really studied netcode or anything like that - and I'm not sure how difficult it'd be to learn it. Are there any good tutorials out there?

Comment: If you're familiar with javascript, it would just be ajax POST and GET request.

Comment: Welp, apparently I'm not that familiar with javascript as I thought. I'll look into ajax, thanks.

Comment: If you are just doing api/server calls, you can also look into dredd(https://dredd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It handles a large portion of the requests using markdown. You can also interact with the requests using hooks.