# Can watir-webdriver submit a form without opening a GUI browser like Chrome?

Tags: ruby, selenium, phantomjs, watir-webdriver

Can I set values for input fields and submit a form using watir-webdriver *without* opening a browser display?

Comment: Yes, try using headless browser. Thanks

Comment: [Have a look here to know more about headless browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549954/java-selenium-how-can-i-get-the-html-of-a-webpage-without-first-loading-the-pag/38550069#38550069). Thanks

Comment: @SaurabhGaur, running `sudo apt-get install xvfb` returns `Abort.`

Comment: You may have to install other system dependencies then. Look at the abort error and see if it tells you something is missing.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of your previous question - [Can watir-webdriver run chrome on a GUI-less server? Is there a GUI-less browser it can use?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40065707/1200545)?

Answer (score 1):

If you install the `headless` gem (and its system dependencies) it should be easy to start the browser in headless scope:

```
Headless.ly do
  # start your browser
end
```

Comment: Yes, but `sudo apt-get install xvfb` is required before `gem install headless`, and when I run `sudo apt-get install xvfb` I get `Abort.` It's weird.

Comment: It just says abort, nothing else?